# When I make a draggable clone how to retain the height and width of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
$("li", $taskList).draggable({
    helper : "clone",
    revert : "invalid"
});
```

While dragging the element I want the same height and width should be retained.

Comment: What do you mean by same offset?

Comment: div offset before dragging

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on Prasad's answer - to keep the width and height of the original item:

```
$(el).draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function (event, ui) {
    var w = $(this).css('width');
    var h = $(this).css('height');
    ui.helper.css('width', w).css('height', h);
  }
});
```

(Edited to add in height)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li", $taskList).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.helper.animate({
            width: 80,
            height: 50
        });
    }
});
```

It's work for me. while dragging we can set height and width of the colne.